# Two-Way Fixed Effects Model in R - Error - Multicollinearity

Tags: r, panel-data, multicollinearity, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to build a two way fixed effects model (entity-specific and time-specific fixed effects). However, when I run the fixed effects code in R, I get the following error message:

```
Error in solve.default(vcov(x)[names.coefs_wo_int, names.coefs_wo_int],  : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 8.60051e-32
```

For context, this is my model using the plm package in R:

```
model <- plm(log(sales) ~ log(price) + log(price)*product_cat + log(price)*promo_type, 
                   data = panel_data, 
                   index = c("product_id", "date"),
                   model = "within", 
                   effect = "twoways")
```

For some context, within my model, both log(sales) and log(price) are numerical variables, while product_cat and promo_type are categorical variables. It has come to my attention that the error I'm facing suggests that the matrix may not be invertible, possibly due to multicollinearity.

Any suggestions on how can I solve the multicollinearity problem?

Comment: I would first look at a crosstab of the two dummy variables and see if there are empty cells. If not, then I think the problem (which certainly does seem like collinearity) is probably something to do with how you specified the details in plm.  Did you look at the vignettes for that package?

Comment: @PeterFlom many thanks for your answer and suggestions! Much appreciated! I did check the crosstab of the dummies, and there are no missing values. In regards to the plm vignette, I did have a look at it, and it seems I implemented the plm formula correctly. However, the most weird part is that before my model (the formula above) was working, but now it gives the error. In order to deal with multicollinearity, I tried to compute the VIF values, but it gives an error. So I'm unsure which predictors/interaction effects are causing the collinearity.

Comment: Not sure that this causes the issue, but `log(price) + log(price)*product_cat` could simply be `log(price)*product_cat` since the star already generates the base effects for the interaction.

Comment: It could also be that `product_id`s linearly combine into `product_cat`, as each product likely always is part of one category, so that demeaning in FE means that we cannot estimate the effect of category in the interaction. But then R might just drop that variable and not return an error (in any case, I haven't been able to reproduce this error with some mock data).